# How do I use the "Inoperative Components or Visual Aids Table" when more than one component is inop?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, iaps

I can't fully seem to understand this sentence:

> If more than one component is inoperative, each minimum is raised to the highest minimum required by any single component that is inoperative

Can someone please explain this for me? Perhaps using a scenario with an approach where some equipment is inoperative?

[image]

Comment: I believe it means your RVR would be 4500 and your visibility would be 1/2 mile since those are the maximum values for any single failure.

Answer (score 1):

It means that in case of more than one inoperative component, the additions are not cumulative.  For example, if a particular ILS is authorized for 1800 RVR, and the approach lights AND touchdown zone lighting are inop, the increase in minimums is the largest single penalty (to 4000 RVR).  You do not add the penalties for multiple failures.